# Why am I unable to select all records in one table that don't exist in another table?

Tags: sql, database, subquery, amazon-redshift

I have two tables like:

```
table_1:

col1
A
B
C
D


table_2

col1
B
D
F
E
```

Desired output:

```
A
C
```

I want to select all records in `col1` of `table_1` that aren't in `col1` of `table_2`. In actuality, `table_1` has 65000+ rows and `table_2` has around 2000 rows. My query:

```
SELECT col1
FROM table_1
WHERE col1 NOT IN (SELECT col1 FROM table_2)
```

This returns no records. However, the reverse works as intended when I select all records in `table_2` that don't exist in `table_1`. I have double checked that I do have records in both tables and when manually checking if values exist or not by doing:

```
SELECT * FROM table_2 WHERE col1 = 'C'
```

And this produces no records as expected. I have also done:

```
SELECT col1
FROM table_1
WHERE col1 IN (SELECT col1 FROM table_2)
```

And this produces all mutual records as intended. I have also done:

```
SELECT col1
FROM table_2
WHERE col1 NOT IN (SELECT col1 FROM table_1)
```

And this produces all records in `table_2` that aren't in `table_1` as intended.

Why is my query just not working for records that are in one table but not the other?

Comment: What are the **exact** data-types of those columns? If they're string/text values are you certain there's no outer whitespace or `COLLATION` interfering? What if you change the query to an anti-join? Show us your `CREATE TABLE` statements.

Comment: Can you provide a DB<>Fiddle that demonstrates?

Comment: So these are actually temp tables that I created using `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE AS`. Is there a way to check the data type of a column easily using Redshift? I'm fairly certain they're all string/text though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've shown you could see if a *not exists* criteria serves the purpose. If this doesn't work as expected then almost certainly there's something different, eg collation, that we don't know about.

```
select col1
from table_1 t1
where not exists (select * from table_2 t2 where t2.col1 = t1.col1);
```

Comment: This seems to work somehow! Can you possibly explain how?

Comment: I don't use Redshift so I can only guess it would be to do with how the tables are joined and how the data is compared it may be agnostic to something the not-in is affected by. You might present both queries in a new question perhaps and see if someone with Redshift-specific knowledge might know.